# Index of products in the Brauer group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0.
Let us consider two elements $A,B \in$ Br$(k)$, which are not inverse to each other.

What is the index of the product $A \otimes B$ in Br$(k)$?

I assume that since the index of an algebra is just the degree of its underlying division algebra, that the index of the product above is just the product of
the indexes of $A, B$.

Maybe this is too obvious to be pointed out in any book i found.

The period is a whole other story of course. No: I did no confuse the index with the period.

Comment: No, this is quite false. The problem is that the tensor product of two division algebras need not be a division algebra - indeed if it were there couldn't be inverses!

Comment: Ok, this is a "great" answer. So you say that one can not tell? I mean if you tensor two non split quaternion algebras ($ind(A) = ind(B) = 2$) the resulting index could not be different from 1 or  2? Do you have some contrete example of calculations?

Comment: You didn't allow $A$ and $B$ to be inverses but it's easy to get around this. Over a field whose Brauer group has elements of large index, let $X$ be an element with large index, $Y$ be an element with small index, and set $A = X, B = X^{op} \otimes Y$. Then $A$ has large index (the index of $X$), $B$ has index at least $1$, but $A \otimes B$ has small index (the index of $Y$).

Comment: Ok. But say $A$ has index $2$ and $B$ has index $13$. What are other possibilities for the index of the product than "$26$ ? I mean these algebras cant be inverse to each other.

Comment: $A \otimes B \cong M_n(D)$ for some division algebra $D$, and so has dimension $n^2 \dim D$. So a priori the index could be any number of the form $\frac{\text{ind}(A) \text{ind}(B)}{n^2}$; in your example the index must be $26$ because $26$ is squarefree.

Comment: Ok, then at least these cases are covered.